# Cannot read foreign characters in MySQL database (Xampp and Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Currently I am working on Ruby on Rails web application (open sourced software). I have encountered problem while reading foreign characters in my table data, both using phpmyadmin and mysql workbench.

The RoR application is using a InnoDB type database. All the tables were completely built using utf-8 and utf8_general_ci. This is confirmed as I already tried saving the whole database as .sql and searched for latin encoding. None of any latin encoding come out.

my machine version is as following:

- php 5.4, mysql 5.5.36
- rails 2.3.8, ruby 1.8.7

Tried several solutions including:

- tried to add 'encoding: utf8' in development.rb. 'rake db:create' without problem, but when using gem install plugins is problematic. The error is 'cannot find database adapter'. I searched for the error and checked my development.rb where the adapter is indeed correct, all the formats in the code are also correct.
- tried adding encoding_internal :: encoding_utf8, encoding_external :: encoding_utf8 in evironment.rb
- tried to change the server connection collation (landing page in phpmyadmin) from utf8mb4_general_ci to utf8_general_ci but 'loading' message appeared i.e keeps on hanging.  and it never seems to get changed even mysql restarted in Xampp console
- The ideal environment for the app is rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7 therefore I cannot upgrade any of them.

I did click on 'variables' tab in phpmyadmin but don't really know which part to change. For this I would like to know if we have to change all non utf8, for example latin, binary etc to utf8...in other words making all settings consists of utf8 only?

The unwanted rubbish characters was some of like this 'Ø´ ØªÙˆÙ¾' instead of intended foreign characters. The intended foreign characters are displayed correctly in views (web browsers) but not in phpmyadmin.

I am very new to mysql, phpmyadmin and RoR configurations. Please help.

Thanks.

Edit:
I also noticed that if I upload the data in the intended characters, it will appears as it is in the database (which is what I want to see for the characters).

Comment: When you say "The intended foreign characters are displayed correctly in views", are you talking about in your Rails app views?  If so that suggests that they are being correctly stored in the database, and correctly loaded from the database into rails.  Is that the case?

Comment: @MaxWilliams it is rendered perfectly in the view. For example, in the view, there are forms to prompt users enter the data. the data can be non english (foreign) and english characters. when the form is accepted and displayed back to the users, they can see all the characters (including foreign characters) perfectly. it only appears garbled in database when I view it. also when I tried to upload those data in csv form, I can view it perfectly in the database.
Update: The problem lies in the app itself.

Comment: @MaxWilliams cont. from above, the foreign characters are stored as utf-8 encoded in the database. They are decoded when shown in the application. Means I have to explicitly set the database to utf8 when creating them.

Comment: But when creating the database we use Ruby command rake db:create. If we create the db explicitly using a SQL script then does that mean rake db:create should not be used? Sorry if this is an idiot question. I'm just confuse having to create the db explicitly at the  same time.

Comment: Checked the default character set for the database - correct collation and character set... maybe something should be done in the mysql connection configurations??

Comment: Where do you see the broken characters - just in phpmyadmin?  Are they ok in the rails console? What about if you start MySQL in the terminal and look there? Is that what you meant by MySQL workbench?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I saw broken characters in both phpmyadmin and workbench. I used both phpmyadmin and workbench to view the table data containing the garbled characters. It appears all right in the rails app view (in browsers).

Comment: If it's all right in rails then it's obviously nothing wrong with your rails app config.  Can you access the mysql terminal (NOT workbench) from the command line and see what it's like in there?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Hi, finally access the table from terminal. It appears gibberish too, but this time most of the gibberish characters are replaced with "?".. sort of like "???"

Comment: when i export the data in csv form and opened it in notepad & excel, the gibberish data appears as it is. But when I tried to alter the gibberish data into something readable foreign language and import it back to the table, I can see the foreign characters perfectly.

Comment: Since the data appears garbled in the terminal, phpMyAdmin, and Workbench, the problem is certainly your application. This could have several causes, generally either double encoding or using the wrong charset. See https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data for a good overview of the potential pitfalls (even though it's written primarily for PHP developers, the root causes are language independent). As for what your exact problem is, it's tough to tell without seeing more code. My first thought is that you're not properly setting the charset for your application to communicate with MySQL.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch All right, will read the documentation you suggested. I'm actually customizing an open sourced party software named Fedena School System. Since it contains a lot of pieces of code, it would be hard to post them here. I agree though that the problem lies in the application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to configure all the variables for server in phpMyAdmin into utf8 and make sure to add these lines to my.ini under mysql folder in Xampp folder.

just after [mysqld] line, add:

character-set-server = utf8

skip-character-set-client-handshake

restart server and reload the page again.